# TreatControlCAsInput issue.  Is this a bug?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Just ran across the problem described below. If "Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;", you have to press [enter] twice on ReadLine().

I've written some demo code below. I am correct in surmising that this code demonstrate a bug in the .NET 4 framework?

```
        Console.Write("Test 1: Console.TreatControlCAsInput = false\nType \"hello\": ");
        {
            string readline = Console.ReadLine(); // type "hello" [enter].
            Console.WriteLine("You typed: {0}", readline);
            // Prints "hello".
        }

        Console.Write("Test 2: Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true\nType \"hello\": ");
        Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;
        {
            string readline = Console.ReadLine(); // type "hello" [enter].
            Console.WriteLine("You typed: {0}", readline);
            // Should print "hello" - but instead, you have to press [enter] 
            // *twice* to complete the ReadLine() command, and it adds a "\r" 
            // rather than a "\n" to the output (so it overwrites the original line)
        }

        // This bug is a fatal error, because it makes all ReadLine() commands unusable.

        Console.Write("[any key to exit]");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: I could reproduce this on Windows 7. Enter seems be doing the function of the **HOME** button

Comment: I see it reported in 2006 where is is marked as closed, by design. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/226101/console-treatcontrolcasinput-true-breaks-readline

Comment: @parapura rajkumar Actually, it seems to be printing \r (carriage return) instead of \n (line feed) when [enter] is pressed, and also requiring two [enter]s to be pressed to complete the ReadLine().

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a [known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/226101/console-treatcontrolcasinput-true-breaks-readline) with the Windows Console subsystem and has been reported on Microsoft Connect back in 2006.

> Posted by Microsoft on 22/05/2007 at 12:37
>
> Hello ARos, Thank you for reporting this issue in System.Console. The
>   behavior exists with the Windows Console subsystem, as demonstrated
>   with the attached Win32 C application. I have reported the issue to
>   the Windows Console subsystem owner.
>
> Thanks, Josh

Comment: As a side note: that connect item was closed as "by design".  So Sounds like they decided it was a feature.

Comment: @Chris Lively Amazing "feature" - it breaks ReadLine() so its unusable. I wonder how many developers have collided with this particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

Not a bug on the Framework but it looks like a bug in the [Windows console subsystem](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/226101/console-treatcontrolcasinput-true-breaks-readline).